# Why doesn't a select dropdown allow me to click an item IE but works fine in Firefox, Chrome, etc?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, select, drop-down-menu

I am using the [jquery mega dropdown menu plugin](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/).  In one of the menus, I wanted to add a dropdown box. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome (as seen in screenshot below)

[image]

but in IE, when i click on the select dropdown and hover over one of the item in the select for more than a second, the whole menu disappears (as if it thinks that i am no longer hovering over the menu.

I am able to [reproduce the issue on this example (click on "Sales")](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-plugins/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu/menu2.html)

Any suggestions on how to get a select dropdown showing up on jquery mega menu

Comment: Why is it hard to believe it really looks like that in IE?

Comment: Maybe IE has some sort of out for the mega menu.. Looks like it got mad and spread some white paint over it for funsies.

Comment: Will this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206997/jquery-javascript-ie-hover-doesnt-cover-select-box-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your issue is the plugin's code itself. The probelm:  IE does not consider its "select elements" as part of the actual select option.

Adding this to your jquery code should solve the problem:

```
 $(".mega-hover select").mouseleave(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Please keep me posted.

Comment: i see this issue in IE7 and IE8  ..  i don't understand at all what clicking has anything to do with it . . the website i provided doesn't actually have any select dropdown in submenus unfortunately so that is why i added the screenshot

Comment: Right, But i need to see code in order to help you, a screenshot doesn't really help in this scenario.  The menus on the site you provided work fine in IE7/Ie8 have you have stated, so ill need to see your code as to why menus aren't working.

Comment: i have updated the question (as i solved my first problem) and i provided a link to my issue now with a reproducible example

Comment: Leora, I have updated my answer.  I have trimmed it down to being an IE issue where the select elements of the drop-down aren't considered part of the same element, therefore the menu's dropdown timer gets reset.

Comment: Looks like you copied this answer =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206997/jquery-javascript-ie-hover-doesnt-cover-select-box-options

Comment: How's that possible if I posted my answer before you ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Which version of IE are you having problems with? It works OK in IE7 and IE8 - see sub-menu for "Sale":

LINK EDITED:

http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-plugins/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu/menu2.html

Comment: What is the URL of `menu2.html` on your site?

Comment: @Lee - you are pointing to something on your C drive.  is there a URL for this ??

Comment: @Lee - i figured out why it was not showing.  I now have another issue where if i hover over any of the menu items for too long, the menu disappears (as IE no longer thinks that i am hovering over the menu)

Comment: To be honest Im not sure how easy/if that can be fixed with IE and select lists. You would probably be better simulating a select list instead or switch to using the "click" event for opening/closing the menu

Answer (score 0):

I would guess IE assumes you have left focus from the drop-down menu when you click on a select box, so it tries to hide the menu. You'll have to fix the library code to verify that you are no longer hovering over the menu AND a select box does not have focus. One place to start is the function. Perform your checks first before hiding the menu.

```
function megaOut(){
            var subNav = $('.sub',this);
            $(this).removeClass('mega-hover');
            $(subNav).hide();
            // beforeClose callback;
            defaults.beforeClose.call(this);
        }
```

Comment: This reminds me of an old bug in Windows where the screen rendering engine stuttered, and the only objects that were updated were Flash and select/dropdown objects.