# onmouseover(drop down - option tag) event in chrome not working - php, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mouseover, mousemove

I am facing an issue with mouseover/mousemove event in Chrome - Version 50.0.2661.94 m.The same is working fine in Mozilla.

Requirement : On mouse over of drop down (option tag) I need to display description of each option.

Code :

HTML:

```
<td>
    <select class="div_taskDesc" name="selectedindexid'+rowcounter+'" OnChange="SetDF(\''+rowcounter+'\');" onmousemove="getOptionDesc(this,event);"><?echo $Options_select;?>
    </select>
</td>
```

JavaScript :

```
function getOptionDesc(o, e) { 
    var selected=o.options[o.selectedIndex].text;
    var selecteddesc=o.options[o.selectedIndex].label;
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    console.log(coor); 
    if (selected!=""){ 
         //Code to display description
    }
    else{
         //code to hide description
    }
}
```

Comment: First, can you update your question by indenting your code by 4 spaces in front of each lines, so it can be readable? Then, how do you trigger this function? Add this part too... Because the problem is probably there.

Comment: Calling it in onmousemove="getOptionDesc(this,event);" select tag...and its working in other browsers

Comment: Ok... I see the difference. you're talking about... And I found an answer for you here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038811/ie-and-chrome-dont-fire-a-mouseover-event-for-option-elements

Comment: Strange. So mouseover event doesnt work in Chrome...Right?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206997/jquery-javascript-ie-hover-doesnt-cover-select-box-options they have explained clearly

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try css here?

## idname a:hover{color:#000000;background:#ffffff;}

Comment: I tried, Its not working :( Control is not even going inside.